# Blinking/flashing images in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

My images are blinking when I mouse-over in Firefox.  They work fine on chrome and safari.

I think I've narrowed it down to the  tag that wraps the images, but I don't know why it would cause that problem. (The left image does not have an  tag around them and it is fine, but the right image does, and it's blinking.)

Full HTML: http://mf.atlantadesigngroup.com/firefox.php

Relevent HTML:

```
<div id="portfolio">
  <div class="portfolio"> <img src="images/portfolio/bw/uploaded1.jpg" class="portfolioImg"></div>
  <div class="portfolio"> <a href="firefox.php"> <img src="images/portfolio/bw/uploaded4.jpg" class="portfolioImg"> </a> </div>
</div>
```

Full CSS: http://mf.atlantadesigngroup.com/css/mignonFowler.css

Relevent CSS:

```
/*portfolio page*/
#portfolio{
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 980px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.portfolio{
    display: table-cell;
    height:440px;
    border: #000000 solid 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.portfolioImg{
    height: 100%;
}

.portfolio div{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    background-image: url('../images/captionBg.png');
    background-position: bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.portfolio div p{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 70px;
    color: #c9b52e;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Think it might the 1px border you have on `a:hover, a:visited`, line 110. You can either remove this, or set the image to be displayed `inline` or `inline-block` depending on your needs. There's probably some other fixes, those are the two I found.

Comment: It may be happening because of `display: table` for `#portolifo` and `display: table-cell` for  `.portfolio`. Are you sure you need to use it this way? You could use `float: left` insted or `display: inline-block` for `.portoflio elements`.

Comment: It was the border...thanks Adam!